# Network Unclaimed for ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet

suddenly my ethernet stopped working when I type 
`sudo lshw -C network`

This is the result

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2200000-a2200fff memory:a2000000-a2003fff
```

But I am able to connect to WiFi.

My kernel version is `5.4.0-24-generic`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by reinstalling [this driver from GitHub user ghostrider-reborn](https://github.com/ghostrider-reborn/realtek-r8101-linux-driver).